# Hadoop : find the hostname or IP address based on the process id

Tags: process, hadoop

Is it possible to find the IP address or hostname of who submited a job based on the processid ?

We have some hadoop jobs running for hundreds of hours. We need to know from which local machine it was submitted. We have the process id of that job.

The entire team uses a common UNIX User ID and uses PUTTY to login into the server, so knowing the userid won't help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for running processes. Using `ps` you can get process start time and its tty information. Next you have to check `/var/log/wtmp` file:

```
utmpdump /var/log/wtmp
```

or use `wtmp` wrapper - `last` utility:

```
last
```

Find time of login and corresponding tty. Using trivial analysis it's possible to determine with high probability which host has been used to start the process.